# Как запустить код python3 через sublimeREPL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text

Файл `Packages/sublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`

```
[
 {
    "id": "tools",
    "children":
    [{
        "caption": "SublimeREPL",
        "mnemonic": "r",
        "id": "SublimeREPL",
        "children":
        [
            {"caption": "Python",
            "id": "Python",

             "children":[
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python 3",
                 "id": "repl_python3",
                 "mnemonic": "p",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["/usr//bin/python3", "-i", "-u"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
        }]
    }
 ]
```

Файл `Packages/sublimeREPL/config/main.sublime-menu`

```
[
 {
    "id": "tools",
    "children":
    [{
        "caption": "SublimeREPL",
        "mnemonic": "r",
        "id": "SublimeREPL",
        "children":
        [
            {"caption": "Python",
            "id": "Python",

             "children":[
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python 3",
                 "id": "repl_python3",
                 "mnemonic": "p",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-i", "-u"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: Постарайтесь понятнее объяснить что Вы хотите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполнение программы на Python из SublimeText с установленным package SublimeREPL осуществляется из меню:

```
Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python - RUN current file
```

Либо же, если нужен запуск по сочетанию клавиш, добавьте в Preferences > KeyBindings - User:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
                 "id": "repl_python_run",
                 "mnemonic": "d",
                 "args": {
                 "type": "subprocess",
                 "encoding": "utf8",
                 "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file_basename"],
                 "cwd": "$file_path",
                 "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                 "external_id": "python",
                 "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
   },
]
```

, где ["ctrl+shift+r"] - требуемое сочетание клавиш.

При этом SublimeText выполнит вашу команду системным интерпретатором python, то есть тем, который у вас по-умолчанию вызывается при вводе команды python в командной строке ОС. Если у вас там python 3, то и в SublimeText вызываться будет та же версия.

Comment: Ещё вариант: `Ctrl+Shift+P` → `SublimeREPL:Python` (можно ввести просто `srpy`) → `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при попытке сохранения комбинации клавиш по коду выше я получал ошибку "Error trying to parse settings expected value in packages user preferences sublime settings."
Мне помог следующий код

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
{
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}}
]
```